# dispatch_async in dealloc. How to use it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several controllers that should send some callback after it destroy. 
I use helper for it

```
+ (void) runInMain:(void (^)(void))block
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        block();
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}
```

And run it in -dealloc

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    if (self.hasChanges) {
        [CommonSystem runInMain:^{
            [self.updTarget performSelector:self.updAction withObject:nil];
        }];
    }
}
```

Self is retained in this block? And his members?
Can this code cause crash?
How is the best way to solve this task?

**Update**
In [Apple post](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2109/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010274-CH1-SUBSECTION11) about "The Deallocation Problem" there is some text:

> When you start a secondary thread, it's common for that thread to
>   retain the target object. This happens in numerous circumstances,
>   including:
>  ... 
>  **when you run a block asynchronously and the block
>   references self or an instance variable**

Does it mean that invoke dispatch_async retain self in -dealloc, or it's too late for it?

**Solution**
Wait in destructor to completion of parent handler.
1)

```
[self.updTarget performSelectorOnMainThread:self.updAction withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

2)

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.updTarget performSelector:self.updAction withObject:nil];
});
```

Comment: Best solution is post a notification NSNotificationcenter from dealloc method and listen to it wherever its required.

Comment: after it destroy? that sounds impossible, 'right before the destruction' is much more possible, like what you have there.. 

to achieve what you what, i think you have two choices.. either use `NSNotificationcenter` like @kmithi is saying or use delegate..

Comment: before calling runInMain create variables to SomeType* target = self.updTarget and SEL action = self.updAction. And use them inside block, so in block you will not use self

Comment: @0yeoj I don't recommend the delegate because it will takes its own time to finish the task and comeback to dealloc method. So its good to post a notification and forget it.

Comment: @kmithi, I don't recommend that also.. haha.. at least he'll know that he has two option to do and achieve what he want.. that's his choice.. hahaha.. (evil laugh)..

Answer (score 0):

After destroy no object can send the callback, There are some ways like delegate which can be called from dealloc for any kinda call back data which you can define and use into your controller, also notification is best if you don't want the delegation to implement. There is advanced option method sizzling which you can use with dealloc method customisation if you are calling any parent controller method and you truly know how to handle it but strongly avoid.